# Wrong quotient in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C language and I'm having trouble about this simple arithmetic operation to convert ounce to metric ton. I don't know how to fix it. It's always giving me wrong result.

```
#include<math.h>
#define oz 35273.92

main()
{
    int ounces;
    float mton;
    clrscr();

    printf("Enter ounces: ");
    scanf("%d",&ounces);

    mton = ounces/oz;

    printf("The metric ton is %f.", mton);

    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

I tried entering 70547.84 but the result is wrong.

```
Enter ounces: 70547.84
The metric ton is 0.014026
```

If I enter a number lower than `oz` it gives me -0.000000

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Also, why are you trying to enter fractional digits for a number that you're scanning as an integer?  You know what an integer is right?

Comment: OT: You don't need to `#include <math.h>` for a simple division.

Comment: I get `1.999976` with the program, which is a reasonable result.

Comment: Read [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of *every* used function. Notably of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) whose result (the count of scanned items) you are ignoring wrongly. Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). **Use the debugger `gdb`**

Comment: Also, remember that stdout is line buffered. Better add a `\n` at the end of every `printf` format string, till you understand when you have to use [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush)

Comment: It would be a good idea to echo the input as well as the answer: `printf(“%d ounces is %f metric tonnes\n”`, ounces, mton);` for example.  You should also be coding in C99 or C11 and giving the return type of `main()` as `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I can't reproduce this with my compiler (GCC 6.3.0). The result I get is `1.999976`, which is fairly reasonable. Also I'm not getting `-0.000000` with an input lower than `oz`.

I suggest, that you should use floating point values for `ounces`, as you're inputting a decimal number. If you use `int` you'll not be able to read past the decimal point. You'll get 70547 in `ounces`, with `.84` left in the input stream.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define oz 35273.92

int main() {
    float ounces;
    float mton;
    clrscr();

    printf("Enter ounces: ");
    scanf("%f", &ounces);

    mton = ounces/oz;

    printf("The metric ton is %f.", mton);

    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

This should give you the desired result.